# Round Image corners GM ImageMagic, pass options

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, rounding

Hi I would like to convert some images with rounded corners. I found how this can be done with ImageMagic on their website

```
  convert thumbnail.gif \
    \( +clone -crop 16x16+0+0  -fill white -colorize 100% \
       -draw 'fill black circle 15,15 15,0' \
       -background Red  -alpha shape \
       \( +clone -flip \) \( +clone -flop \) \( +clone -flip \) \
     \) -flatten  rounded_corners_red.png
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded the problem is that I dont know how to pass all this options into GM. I've tried with

```
 gm.in("\( +clone -crop 16x16+0+0  -fill white -colorize 100%
           -draw 'fill black circle 15,15 15,0'
           -background Red  -alpha shape
           \( +clone -flip \) \( +clone -flop \) \( +clone -flip \)
         \) -flatten")
```

but it's not working. And this is how I resize my images

```
var gm = require("gm").subClass({ imageMagick: true })
var _ = require("lodash")
var images = ['1b.jpg', '2b.jpg', '3b.jpg']

_.forEach(images, function(image, key) {

    var img = gm( __dirname + '/' + image )
    var dest = __dirname + '/' + key+'.jpg'
    img.resize('100', '100', '^')
    img.gravity('Center')
    img.crop('100', '100')

    img.in("\( +clone -crop 16x16+0+0  -fill white -colorize 100%
           -draw 'fill black circle 15,15 15,0'
           -background Red  -alpha shape
           \( +clone -flip \) \( +clone -flop \) \( +clone -flip \)
         \) -flatten")

    img.write( __dirname + '/' + key+'.jpg', function (err) {
     if (!err) console.log(' image done! ');
    })

})
```

Comment: Do you want red or transparent corners? Are your images that you want to apply rounded corners to all the same size roughly - and if so, what size?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is to automate this process, so the size of the image in this example is 100x100, but can be different at some point. The image has been resized and cropped as you can see from the example above, so after this I would like to make it with rounded corners. About the background I prefer to be transparent, but if not possible any colour would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe **GraphicsMagick** supports parentheses and that seems a very complicated way of doing things. I think I would make an alpha mask that shows where I want the picture to be opaque/transparent and copy that into the image.

So, in concrete terms:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:none -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,99,99,12,12" mask.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 100x100 gradient:blue-yellow mask.png -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Also, note that you will not be able to store transparent corners in a JPEG output file since JPEG doesn't support transparency.

If you wanted red corners, you could do:

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:red -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,99,99,12,12" -transparent black mask.png
convert -size 100x100 gradient:blue-yellow mask.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Recent versions of ImageMagick do support parenthesis. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis

Comment: @JonAdams I was referring to **GraphicsMagick** not supporting parentheses.

Comment: I don't know about GraphicMagick, but the op was asking about _ImageMagick_, not GM. My point was, that op's original solution using parenthesis could still work in theory... Your answer is a little confusing by switching to talk about GM which is very similar but not exactly the same. I'm not trying saying you're wrong or not (I'm not expert in either tool)—I'm just trying to clarify for future users who may not know the differences between GM and IM. (And even to remind myself, because I find the differences confusing too.)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your original image is a 100x100 green square:

```
gm convert -size 100x100 xc:green input.png
```

[image: Green Square]

First, create the mask:

```
gm convert -size 100x100 xc:none -fill black -draw "roundrectangle 0,0,99,99,10,10" mask.png
```

[image: Mask with rounded corners]

Then, apply the mask to the input image:

```
gm composite -size 100x100 input.png xc:none mask.png output.png
```

[image: Green square with rounded corners]

The way to think about the arguments to `composite` is that first `input.png` is stacked on top of the image `xc:none` (completely obscuring it), and then `mask.png` is used to mask out areas of `input.png`, and reveal parts of `xc:none` underneath.

(See [roundrect](https://github.com/ithinkihaveacat/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/roundrect) for a shell script that rounds the corners of arbitrary-sized images, without requiring intermediate files to be created.)